# Autocreate vhost.conf in Plesk

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

We are running a Server with Plesk 9.2 and are Creating Domains from the Web Interface. The CMS System Used needs a custom vhost.conf file for every domain created and this repetative task is getting boring. Is there a way to automatically create this file in Plesk upon domain creation?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you can customise the default Plesk skeleton files which are used when you create new domains. The files (on Linux at least) can be found here:

```
/var/www/vhosts/.skel/0
```

Just create a conf directory there and put in the vhost.conf file that you need and it should be used for new domains.